# Get line number of Chrome inspected element

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the Chrome browser's Inspect Element function. It opens some kind of tab in my browser, shows me the HTML, and lets me change it and do some kind of preview. When I change it, I want to know where can I see the line number in my source file.  Inspect Element highlights the line of the *element* that I pick, but when I go to the Source tab, there's no highlighted line.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools  please refer that.. It explains how to use the chrome developer tools ( which is what it is called)

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with that: the DOM tree that you see in "inspect element" may not be the same as defined in the HTML file.

JavaScript can modify the DOM tree in arbitrary ways. Afterwards, it's impossible to match a certain node to the original source.

So, your task is nearly impossible and that is why Dev Tools do not try to do it.

Comment: Not near impossible. Dreamweaver does it. I'm trying to riddle out how.